# One page animation framework for jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, navigation

I'm developing a very animation heavy, one page website atm and I'm trying to find tutorials and/or code on the subject.

The website is basically built in several sections that all reside on a canvas. The user should be able to scroll to different sections on the canvas and also expand sections so that they take up the entire viewport.

It's similar to many other one page sites out there but you should be able to scroll in all kinds of directions and and like I said certain sections should be expandable.

I'm ideally looking for a jQuery plugin/framework that allows for this type of animation. Of course I need it to be accessible and preferably lightweight (I don't need a bunch of stuff built in, just URL handling etc).

I've googled and checked other sites as well as considered coding this all myself, but if someone has recently done something similar or knows of a promising framework I'd love to know.

Edit: It would be awesome if the framework also supports animating objects in the sections themselves. So that text and images could slide in from the sides after a section has been scrolled to.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested I ended up using jQuery.scrollTo along with jQuery.localScroll. I had to make a minor change to localScroll to allow for a .selected-class on the link that was last clicked. I also built a little system for handling horizontal sections. It all turned out quite alright.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps combining something like [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com/) along with a scrolling canvas like [ZyngaScroller](https://github.com/TimHeckel/ZyngaScroller) would achieve what you're looking for?

*Disclaimer* I wrote the ZyngaScroller jquery plugin.

Comment: ZyngaScroller looks pretty nice. Not sure if it's exactly what I'm looking for though. Just for clarity; when I said "canvas" I didn't actually mean an html `canvas` element, just that each section is laid out on a "canvas" if you know what I mean.

Comment: Got it. I was a bit confused by that. The [original Zynga Scroller is here](https://github.com/zynga/scroller), and it has lots of examples (paging, zooming, etc). Could be something you're after...hope this helps.